# Difference between ことが and ことは

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, particle-こと

What is the difference in the meanings of the following sentences when 事がある is replaced with 事はある?

- 週末はたいてい家で休んでいるがたまに公園に行く事がある。
- 週末はたいてい家で休んでいるがたまに公園に行く事はある。

I could find the grammar form ことがある in books and the internet but nothing for ことはある.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, がある is neutral - so it simply means "... but I sometimes go to the park". When you say はある it implies that's the only thing that happens. I.e. it means "... but I sometimes go to the park (but I don't go anywhere else)"